# problems in res.json() in node and express

Tags: node.js, express

I have to implement HTTP `POST` request. I have a document(id is the title of the document and result1 stores the content of the document) in my database which I need to `POST`. I have created the resource(201 status) but I have to show the href field of the newly created resource in the web page.

When I try to do it with res.json (`res.json(obj.Link);)`. It gives an error which is:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

I need help in printing this href field.
There is no problem with errorWrap() and the routers has been set already.

```
    function doAdd(app){
  return errorWrap(async function(req, res) {
    try {
        //fething the data
        const id = req.params.id;
        const result1 = await app.locals.finder.docContent(id);
        let obj={
            Content: result1,
            Link:[{rel : "self",
            href : baseUrl(req,DOCS)}]
        };


      // this is for posting:
      obj = req.body;
      let id1 =JSON.stringify(id); 
      let results = await app.locals.finder.addContent(id1,result1);
      // res.append("obj.Link");
      res.append('Location', baseUrl(req) + '/' + obj.id );

      res.json(obj.Link) // gives an error
      res.sendStatus(CREATED);

    }
    catch(err) {
      const mapped = mapError(err);
      res.status(mapped.status).json(mapped);
    }
  });

}
/** Return base URL of req for path.
 *  Useful for building links; Example call: baseUrl(req, DOCS)
 */
function baseUrl(req, path='/') {
  const port = req.app.locals.port;
  const url = `${req.protocol}://${req.hostname}:${port}${path}`;
  return url;
}
```

Comment: What is the context, what is res? Looks like it has already been sent.

Comment: res object represents the HTTP response that an Express app sends when it gets an HTTP request.

Comment: you can't call `res.sendStatus` after `res.json` because `res.json` already sent the response

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is this code:

```
res.json(obj.Link);//response is sent here
res.sendStatus(CREATED);/* response status modified
                         * after sent and resend-attempted erroneously
                         */
```

It should be changed to (use [res.status()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.status)):

```
res.status(CREATED).json(obj.Link);
```

---

It is easy to see why after reading these excerpts from the API docs (we can't send the response twice):

[res.json()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json)

> *Sends* a JSON response.

[res.sendStatus()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendStatus)

> Sets the response HTTP status code to statusCode *and send its string representation as the response body.*

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue before as well. All REST calls accept a single response. So, in your scenario the possible case would be that res.sendStatus(CREATED) line is failing and when it comes to catch block it is trying to reset the status header of response which is already sent.